# How to show popup window in another popup window in android

Tags: android, popupwindow

I want to show popup inside another popup while not dismissing first one.it looks like this

[image]

My main class is as follows

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    location = CommonMethod.locateView(v);
    showMyPresentationPopup(mContext, location);
}

private void showMyPresentationPopup(final Context context, Rect loaction) {
    int popupWidth = convertDipToPixels(400);
    int popupHeight = convertDipToPixels(500);
    String statictext;
    List<String> mResults = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        statictext = "Presentatation "+i+" Name Here";
        mResults.add(statictext);
    }
    PresentationListAdapter mAdapter = new PresentationListAdapter(DashboardActivity.this, mResults);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     final  View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.presentation, null);


    ListView mListView =(ListView)layout.findViewById(R.id.presentationlistid); 
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    mListView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

    displayPopUp(layout,popupWidth, popupHeight,myPresentation,location);
}
// Creating the PopupWindow
public void displayPopUp(View layout,int popupWidth,int popupHeight,View v, Rect location){
mPresentationList = new PopupWindow(mContext);
mPresentationList.setFocusable(true);
mPresentationList.setContentView(layout);
mPresentationList.setWidth(popupWidth);
mPresentationList.setHeight(popupHeight);
mPresentationList.setTouchable(true);
mPresentationList.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
mPresentationList.setOutsideTouchable(true);

 mPresentationList.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
            mPresentationList.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

});
mPresentationList.showAsDropDown(v, -convertDipToPixels(20), 0);
```

}

My getview method i which i am trying to open another popup

```
@Override
public View getView(int pos,  View convertview, final ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Viewholder holder;

    if(convertview==null){  
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertview=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.presentationitem, null,false);
    holder=new Viewholder();

    holder.Title=(TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.presentationtitle);
    holder.mRefresh=(Button)convertview.findViewById(R.id.refreshid);
    holder.mDelete=(Button)convertview.findViewById(R.id.deleteid);
    holder.mDelete.setFocusable(false);
    holder.mRefresh.setFocusable(false);
    holder.mDelete.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    holder.mRefresh.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);


    convertview.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder=(Viewholder)convertview.getTag();
    }
        Log.e("adapter5453===>",wifilist.get(pos));
        holder.Title.setText(wifilist.get(pos));
        holder.mRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int popupWidth = 250;
                int popupHeight = 100;

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sync_dialog, null);
                displayRefreshPopUp(layout,popupWidth, popupHeight,v,location);
            }
        });

        convertview.setTag(R.string.close, wifilist.get(pos));
    return convertview;
}

static class Viewholder{

    TextView Title;
    Button mRefresh;
    Button mDelete;


}

public void displayRefreshPopUp(View layout,int popupWidth,int popupHeight,View v, Rect location){
    mRefreshPopUp = new PopupWindow(context);
    mRefreshPopUp.setContentView(layout);
    mRefreshPopUp.setWidth(popupWidth);
    mRefreshPopUp.setHeight(popupHeight);
    mRefreshPopUp.setTouchable(true);
    mRefreshPopUp.setFocusable(true);
    mRefreshPopUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    mRefreshPopUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    mRefreshPopUp.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
            mRefreshPopUp.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
    mRefreshPopUp.showAsDropDown(v, -20, 0);
    //mRefreshPopUp.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
```

}
  }

I am getting following error.

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@4194d750 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would question the usability of this feature. How will that secondary popup be dismissed? There is limited available UI on most Android screens as it is, are you sure you want to eat away more visible landscape for a tooltip? With space as limited as it is, adding yet another UI element that covers up something possibly useful (or another active area that accepts finger-input) not only makes it hard to read the contents, but increases the risk that a user will accidentally hit another active area (say, a nearby button like the close button above and to the right of that, in your image...)

Comment: Will a `ContextMenu` not work for the second pop up?

Comment: Basically there is a delete image in each row.On click of the delete image that second popup will appear as warning popup to ask "Are you sure to delete this item?"On click of yes button the item will be deleted.This is client requirement.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also doing similar stuff here http://stackoverflow.com/q/37784227/4754141

Answer (score 1):

What if you don't do it as a window.  have it be a hidden element of the row itself.  show/hide it, and it will layer over the rows before it due to simple child order.  This gives you full control over its appearance and also gives you the ability to avoid struggling with fancy popup hacks.

Answer (score 0):

I think *instead of using it as POP Up you can just **hide / show** the second pop* which you can add in the first pop up layout but keep it hidden until you need it.

Comment: please see the attached image.We want to open the popup on the list item of each row

Comment: Then add the pop up code in onItemClickListener in the Activity.class. I don't think that you can get a proper context to show the pop from the ListAdapter.class